# Use apply over rows

Tags: r, row, apply

I have a simple dataframe.

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
```

I would like to divide the entries in each row by the sum of all entries in that row, and get this:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  0.08 0.33 0.58
2  0.13 0.33 0.53
3  0.16 0.33 0.50
```

It's pretty simple to use `mydf[1,]/sum(mydf[1,])` and repeat it 3 times, but this is tedious.

I have an intuitive feeling that an apply function would work.

I have a vague notion I need to:
1)  Put `mydf[1,]/sum(mydf[1,])` in a functional wrapper
2)  use `apply(myfunction, 1, mydataframe)`

But I'm not sure what the arguments to `myfunction` would be.

I'm a little confused on this and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow=3))
dat / rowSums(dat)
```

You could also use `apply`, but it will return a matrix (and require you to transpose with `t`).

```
t(apply(dat, 1, FUN=function(x) x / sum(x)))
```

Comment: Sorry, my first solution was wrong, because it transposes. Fixed.

Comment: So an `apply` function is unnecessary in this case.  If I were to want to practice using `apply`, would this be a good exercise?

Comment: You could use `apply` (I fixed my `apply` solution), but I think the `colSums` solution is little more transparent and saves a transpose and recast as data frame (`apply` returns a matrix).

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer.  I will study `apply` elsewhere.

Comment: @MattO'Brien - I think it's worthwhile and makes code a little more readable and modular. Here's a great [summary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega/7141669#7141669).

Comment: Interesting how that link starts off by subtly implying that the `pylr` package is probably better!

Comment: `ddply` and `plyr` are fantastic. I tend to stick to base R when I can, but I don't have a good reason.